# Configuration concept and implementation

Tags: java, json, configuration

I created an API to load, save and read user configuration in my application. I've a `Configuration` interface which provides the basic methods to read, save and read configuration data and then in the application I've the implementation `JsonConfiguration`.

I tried to keep the Configuration interface as generic as possible. So I didn't make any assumption about how the settings are stored, it can be plain text as well as something else.

This is my `Configuration` interface:

```
public interface Configuration {
  /**
   * Called when the configuration should load the settings
   *
   * @param inputStream In this stream you can found the settings of
   *                    the user.
   *                    An implementation can decide what is inside this
   *                    stream.
   *                    Example: If an implementation
   *                    uses JSON to save and read settings, it should
   *                    assume that this stream contains a valid json.
   *                    If it doesn't, it is allowed to throw
   *                    any exception since it's not
   *                    their job to convert the stream to your
   *                    format.
   *                    Do not close the stream. You don't own it.
   */
  void load(@NotNull final InputStream inputStream);

  /**
   * Called when the configuration should save ALL the settings
   *
   * @param outputStream Write in this stream the settings of the
   *                     user in the form of the implementation.
   *                     Do not close the stream. You don't own it.
   *
   * @throws IOException Throw if something went wrong during the
   *                     save process
   */
  void save(@NotNull final OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException;

  /**
   * @param name The setting name
   * @return The setting as integer (if it's an integer)
   *         or NumberFormatException if not
   */
  @NotNull
  OptionalInt getAsInt(@NotNull final String name);

  @NotNull
  OptionalDouble getAsDouble(@NotNull final String name);

  @NotNull
  OptionalLong getAsLong(@NotNull final String name);

  @NotNull
  Optional<String> getAsString(@NotNull final String name);

  @NotNull
  Optional<Boolean> getAsBoolean(@NotNull final String name);

  /**
   * Set the value
   *
   * @param name The name of the setting
   * @param value The value to save
   * @param <T> The type of the value
   */
  <T> void set(@NotNull final String name, @NotNull final T value);
}
```

(I've removed documentation from `getAsX` since it's the same.) (Yes, I know there is no `getAsFloat`, I will add it after the review.)

As you can see, the concept of `save`/`load` and `read` are mixed in the same interface. My first question is, should I move the two concepts in two interfaces? Maybe using a `Factory` to load and save the settings and `Configuration` will only handle the reading of the data.

This is the implementation, `JsonConfiguration`, which stores data in a JSON format:

```
public class JsonConfiguration implements Configuration {
  private Map<String, ConfigurationSection> configurations = new HashMap<>();

  @Override
  public void load(@NotNull final InputStream inputStream) {
    final JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    final JsonObject root = parser.parse(new InputStreamReader(inputStream)).getAsJsonObject();

    for (final Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : root.entrySet()) {
      final String confName = entry.getKey();

      final ConfigurationSection configuration = new JsonConfigurationSection();
      configuration.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(
              entry
                  .getValue()
                  .toString()
                  .getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
      );

      configurations.put(confName, configuration);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void save(@NotNull final OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
    final Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Configuration>>() {}.getType();
    final OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
    final JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter(out);

    new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(JsonConfigurationSection.class, new JsonConfigurationSectionSerializer())
        .create()
        .toJson(configurations, type, writer);

    writer.flush();
    out.flush();
  }

  @NotNull
  private <T> Optional<T> get(@NotNull final String name) {
    final int dotSeparatorPosition = name.indexOf('.');

    if (dotSeparatorPosition == -1) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(name + " is not a correct user preference setting name");
    }

    final String section = name.substring(0, dotSeparatorPosition);
    final String element = name.substring(dotSeparatorPosition + 1);

    if (!configurations.containsKey(section)) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Section " + section + " doesn't exists.");
    }

    return configurations.get(section).get(element);
  }

  @NotNull
  @Override
  public OptionalInt getAsInt(@NotNull final String name) {
    final Optional<String> optional = get(name);
    return !optional.isPresent() ? OptionalInt.empty() : OptionalInt.of(Integer.parseInt(optional.get()));
  }

  @NotNull
  @Override
  public OptionalDouble getAsDouble(@NotNull final String name) {
    final Optional<String> optional = get(name);
    return !optional.isPresent() ? OptionalDouble.empty() : OptionalDouble.of(Double.parseDouble(optional.get()));
  }

  @NotNull
  @Override
  public OptionalLong getAsLong(@NotNull final String name) {
    final Optional<String> optional = get(name);
    return !optional.isPresent() ? OptionalLong.empty() : OptionalLong.of(Long.parseLong(optional.get()));
  }

  @NotNull
  @Override
  public Optional<String> getAsString(@NotNull final String name) {
    return get(name);
  }

  @NotNull
  @Override
  public Optional<Boolean> getAsBoolean(@NotNull final String name) {
    final Optional<String> optional = get(name);
    return !optional.isPresent() ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(Boolean.parseBoolean(optional.get()));
  }

  /**
   * Sets the value of a section. The name
   * is composed of: sectionName.entryName
   *
   * If the section doesn't exists it will
   * be created.
   *
   * If the entryName doesn't exists it will
   * be created.
   *
   * @param name The name of the setting
   * @param value The value to save
   * @param <T> The type of the value
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException If the name passed is not of the format: sectionName.entryName
   */
  @Override
  public <T> void set(@NotNull final String name,
                      @NotNull final T value) {
    final int dotSeparatorPosition = name.indexOf('.');

    if (dotSeparatorPosition == -1) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(name + " is not a correct user preference setting name");
    }

    final String sectionName = name.substring(0, dotSeparatorPosition);
    final String element = name.substring(dotSeparatorPosition + 1);

    ConfigurationSection section = configurations.get(sectionName);

    if (section == null) {
      section = new JsonConfigurationSection();

      configurations.put(sectionName, section);
    }

    section.set(element, value.toString());
  }
}
```

Since I don't make any assumption in the `Configuration` interface, the concept of "sections" exists only in the implementation and the user access an entry in a section using the notation `sectionName.entryName`.

The interface `ConfigurationSection` is without documentation:

```
public interface ConfigurationSection {
  void load(@NotNull final InputStream inputStream);
  void save(@NotNull final OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException;
  <T> Optional<T> get(@NotNull final String name);
  <T> void set(@NotNull final String name, @NotNull final T value);
}
```

and the implementation:

```
public class JsonConfigurationSection implements ConfigurationSection {
  @NotNull
  private ConcurrentMap<String, Object> values = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

  @Override
  public void load(@NotNull final InputStream inputStream) {
    values = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    final JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    final JsonObject root = parser.parse(new InputStreamReader(inputStream)).getAsJsonObject();

    for (final Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : root.entrySet()) {
      final String key = entry.getKey();
      final JsonElement value = entry.getValue();

      if (value.isJsonPrimitive()) {
        final JsonPrimitive primitive = value.getAsJsonPrimitive();
        values.put(key, primitive.getAsString());
      } else if (value.isJsonNull()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("null is not a valid parameter");
      } else if (value.isJsonArray()) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Arrays not supported yet");
      } else if (value.isJsonObject()) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Objects not supported yet");
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void save(@NotNull final OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
    final Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>() {}.getType();
    final OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    final JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter(out);

    new Gson().toJson(values, type, writer);

    writer.flush();
    out.flush();
  }

  @NotNull
  @Override
  public <T> Optional<T> get(@NotNull final String name) {
    return Optional.ofNullable((T) values.get(name));
  }

  @Override
  public <T> void set(@NotNull final String name,
                      @Nullable final T value) {
    values.put(name, value);
  }

  @NotNull
  Map<String, Object> getValues() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(values);
  }
}
```

As you can see from `load` everything is stored as `String` in the map (so yes, `values` can be changed from `<String, Object>` to `<String, String>` but my plan is to support arrays and objects soon... so).

`ConfigurationSection` interface and `Configuration` are pretty similar as interfaces, but have different concepts.

My application has a `Application` interface with a `getConfiguration` method so Plugins/Application use it to access a `Configuration` object and read settings. The fact that the concept of save/load is of the `Boot` class only (which prepare/load etc the application) it could be an incentive to use a factory instead of the current interface (so I hide the two things).

I'm planning to add a `Transformer` concept to convert a configuration format to another, but it's just an idea for now.

My questions:

1. As I said, the concepts `save`/`load` and `read` are mixed together in one interface, make sense separate them and implement a `Factory` to load and save settings?
2. I want to remove the `throws IOException` from `save` because it's not consistent with `load` which doesn't throw IOException.
3. Can I improve the `load` of `JsonConfigurationSection`? The `if`s seems okay, but maybe could be improved.
4. Any comment? I've read how other languages/framework does it but...

Comment: On your point 2, why can't `load` throw such exception?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel It can, maybe I should add this possibility too...

Comment: It is implied. If the `save` throws, I would expect the `load` to throw as well.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I've added throws IOException to load too since it seems a good way to force who implements Configuration to handle it

Comment: But maybe a Custom exception is better. So every implementation should wrap their exception in this one and who uses it should only handle one case like "ConfigurationLoadFailedException" and "ConfigurationSaveFailedException" because a load can fail if the settings are in the wrong format

Comment: I don't think that will help. Imagine that you try to read/write on `/dev/full`. It won't tell that it is a IO error: it will tell that it was something. What was it? Who knows?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Well, then I think IOException is fine. It will handle most cases where the programmer can do something about it. If there was other cases (like the one you said) then fail is the best thing to do since the programmer can't recover from unknown errors

Comment: I'm not sure if you agree or not with me... But, if there were other cases, the best is to show some very detailed information to the programmer. Or show what you have so you can debug. Now, imagine that you are a programmer. And you are trying to read `A`. But your code crashed before and the handler to `A` wasn't released and the file was left opened and locked. With an IOException, you know where to look at. With a `ConfigurationLoadFailedException`, you don't know if it was a bug in your code or another thing

Comment: Well, the `ConfigurationLoadFailedException` have the cause (`IOException`) so you know what went wrong. With a `ConfigurationLoadFailedException` I will force the configuration programmer to do `try {} catch(Exception e) { throw new ConfigurationLoadFailedException(e); } ` so the methods always fail with ConfigurationLoadFailedException and in the load settings code one can do `catch (ConfigurationLoadFailedException e) { Alert("Ops");}` to inform the user. If your point was that with a `ConfigurationLoadFailedException` one will lose information it won't happen

Comment: But a `catch(Exception e) {}` (in the configuration.load code) is ugly, and I don't think that the programmer can recover from every situation @IsmaelMiguel (most of the time the catch code will just say "close the application")

Comment: If it will have the reason accessible to the code, then I don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: @MarcoAcierno You should catch `IOException` or `SQLException`, or whatever may happen rather than `Exception`. In some rare cases, you may also catch `RuntimeException`, but this is usually a sign of an unexpected bug and then it's damn unsure whether anyone can handle it.

Comment: @maaartinus Yeah, that was one of my fear. With IOException the programmer can do something to recover it (right now, my code in case of IOException tries to load default settings  (after asking the user if wants to try or not) if it fails too, just close everything with "Unable to launch") But if something worst happens recover to default settings could just hide the bug and make users unhappy to see their settings lost at every launch

Comment: @MarcoAcierno But if you switch to a database, then `IOException` makes no sense anymore. Inside you code, `IOException` is fine, but to the outside I'd prefer to present `ConfigurationLoadFailedException`. I guess, the parser throws its own exception and you can use your own to hide the details.

Comment: @maaartinus You are right, if I want to make the Configuration interface as generic as possible I can't use IOException since the load could not require IO at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. As I said, the concepts `save`/`load` and `read` are mixed together in one interface, make sense separate them and implement a `Factory` to load and save settings?

Wells, Java's [`Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) provide similar load/store functionality as well, so I think this is fine.

> 2. I want to remove the `throws IOException` from `save` because it's not consistent with `load` which doesn't throw IOException.

As mentioned by yourself in the lengthy [comments](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/97238/configuration-concept-and-implementation#comment177885_97238), a custom `Exception` class foremost may be more helpful to wrap underlying reasons such as `IOException` (or `SQLException`, `UnknownHostException` etc.). The question then becomes whether you want to stick with checked `Exception` classes or not.

If you prefer checked `Exception` classes, then I think both save/load methods should throw it for consistency. As helpfully explained [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6116020/2754160) and [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=129), checked `Exception`s may be used to indicate to the method's callers that they should be *able to reasonably recover from these scenarios*. For your implementation, I think a checked, custom `Exception` class has its merits for users of your library to explicitly handle cases where *their* configuration could not be initialized properly.

> 3. Can I improve the `load` of `JsonConfigurationSection`? The ifs seems okay, but maybe could be improved.

You may want to consider the *fail-fast* approach here:

```
for (final Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : root.entrySet()) {
    final JsonElement value = entry.getValue();
    if (value.isJsonNull()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("null is not a valid parameter");
    } else if (value.isJsonArray()) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Arrays not supported yet");
    } else if (value.isJsonObject()) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Objects not supported yet");
    } else if (value.isJsonPrimitive()) {
        // note: inlined entry.getKey() and value.getAsJsonPrimitive()
        values.put(entry.getKey(), value.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsString());
    }
}
```

It may not be apparent now, but once your library gains new features, e.g. for array/object support, you can gradually remove the checks *from the top* and append the implementations (or preferably method calls to the new features) *below*.

> 4. Any comment? I've read how other languages/framework does it but...

When you are converting your `Optional<String>` instance to one of the `OptionalInt`/`OptionalLong`, you can rely on the `map().orElse()` chained methods to better convey the conversion:

```
return optional.map(v -> OptionalInt.of(Integer.parseInt(v)))
                .orElse(OptionalInt.empty());
```

I also don't think you really need an `Optional<Boolean>` case... do you really need a tri-state configuration choice, `true`, `false` and `null`? Wouldn't it be easier to just say `true` or `false`?

You also mentioned...

> Since I don't make any assumption in the Configuration interface, the concept of "sections" exists only in the implementation...

Do you intend to support a tree hierarchy of configuration in future versions? That may be worth pondering about...